# Calculate fine from asking user's input values

Tags: c#

The task is to write a program which asks the user the number of books and days while calculating fine.

Some rules:

1. User cannot have more than five books
2. If the number of days is less than 21 then no fine
3. If the number of days is between 22 –30 then fine is 50 cents a day per book for every day that
   is over 21
4. If the number of days is more than that the fine is 80 cents per day per book for every day that is over 21 and message “Membership cancelled” should be displayed

Everything seems to work fine except it asks twice the number of books at the beginning if the value is over 5 or either less than 5, after asking input value for days it asks the number of books again.

```
class Program
    {
        public static int GetBook(int book)
        {
            bool bookAmount = true;
            if (book < 5)
            {
                return book;
            }
            else
            {
              do
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of books: ");
                  book = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                  if (book > 5)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Not valid value, max number of books is 5");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      bookAmount = false;
                  }
              } while (bookAmount);
              return book;  
            }
            
        }

        public static int GetDays(int days)
        {
            return days;
        }

        public static double ConvertFine(int days, int book)
        {
            days = GetDays(days);
            book = GetBook(book);
            double fine = 0;
            
            if (days <= 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine);
            }
            else if (days >= 22 && days <= 30)
            {
                fine += (days - 21) * 0.5 * book;
                Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine + " euros");
            }
            else
            {
                fine += (days - 21) * 0.8* book;
                Console.WriteLine("Membership cancelled!");
                Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine + " euros");
            }
            return fine;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of books: ");
            int book = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(GetBook(book));
            
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of days: ");
            int days = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(GetDays(days));
            
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertFine(days, book));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling GetBook method at two places, it is intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `GetBook` *again* when calculating the fine. Remove the calls to GetBook and GetDays in the `ConvertFine` method.

You can also simplify the GetBook a bit:

```
public static int GetBook(int book)
{
    if (book <= 5)
    {
        return book;
    }

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not valid value, max number of books is 5");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of books: ");
        book = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    } while (book > 5);
    return book;
}

public static int GetDays(int days)
{
    return days;
}

public static double ConvertFine(int days, int book)
{
    double fine = 0;

    if (days <= 21)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine);
    }
    else if (days >= 22 && days <= 30)
    {
        fine += (days - 21) * 0.5 * book;
        Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine + " euros");
    }
    else
    {
        fine += (days - 21) * 0.8 * book;
        Console.WriteLine("Membership cancelled!");
        Console.WriteLine("Fine is: " + fine + " euros");
    }
    return fine;
}
```